# Angular Nested Route Not Calling Component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've got a nested route that I am trying to get working. When I try to navigate to the nested route like so:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/project/' + this.project._id + '/shot/' + row._id);
```

it changes the route in the browser to look like it should. Eg:

```
http://localhost:4200/project/5cdc30c20d86931b180de39b/shot/5cdc31170d86931b180de3b2
```

However, the ShotComponent never gets instantiated!

The app.routes.ts looks like this.

```
{ 
  path: 'project',
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProjectListComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':_id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'shot/:_id',
      component: ShotComponent
    }]
  }]
}
```

If I make the shot route a non-nested route the component gets instantiated properly. I presume I have something wrong here. Any ideas? No errors are getting generated in the console or in the angular cli

Comment: Would you create an online example to reproduce the issue? https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to add different name to shot id

```
{ 
  path: 'project',
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProjectListComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':_id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'shot/:_shotid',
      component: ShotComponent
    }]
  }]
}
```